# Two ExpandableListView one under the other Issue

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

[image: A normal case (what it should like)]

[image: The group is also included in scrolling part]

**What i want is, the below expandablelistview's group must not be included in the scrolling part as in the second picture**. So what should i do?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FBFBE3">

<TextView android:id="@+id/clearFilter"
    android:textSize="17sp" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:typeface="monospace"/>

<ExpandableListView android:layout_marginStart="5dp"  android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/notesList"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:childDivider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" android:groupIndicator="@null"/>

<ExpandableListView android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp" android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/checkList"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:childDivider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
```

Comment: show the code u have tried

Comment: There is no code, i can only show layout xml

Comment: try creating different `LinearLayouts` for both `ListViews`

Comment: U mean; for the groups i use a linearlayout and play with it touch event and  the childs must be listview?

Comment: place your `ExpandableListViews` in different `<LinearLayouts>`

Comment: No it didn't work. I  think the problem is builtin scroll view inside listviews.

Comment: change the main layout i.e LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and then place the second layout below first layout(layouts containing listviews) in the main RelativeLayout